# In eclipse, this reference is automatically getting deleted on save. How do i change the settings?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project that i fetched from GIT.
In all the files, there is a this reference for each variable and method.
When I imported into the eclipse, change something and save the file, all the this references are getting deleted where ever it is not necessary.

```
    this.method1() call is changing to method1() on save
```

How do  i update the settings so that eclipse doesn't make any changes to these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

settings while saving the file can be updated in eclipse using below steps.

1. Go to Preferences
2. Type Save Actions in the search or go to Java -> Editor -> Save Actions
3. Click on "Configure" button in Additional actions section
4. Go to "Member Accesses" in the top menu
5. Here, you can update the settings on what should happen to field and method references on saving the file.